# Make windows app fit to screen size instead of static size

Tags: windows-8.1, windows

I'm working on a windows app in order to learn how to make them in general, and one issue I'm continuously having is the fact that when I go test it, the controls only take up a portion of the screen because they are sized to fit a smaller screen. How can I make them fit for all screens? If I need to provide screenshots to illustrate this point I can.. using forms this was accomplished via docking, but the apps don't seem to have that same capability.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "windows app" you mean a Windows Runtime app, probably in Xaml.

You can get dock-like behavior by using the [VerticalAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.verticalalignment.aspx) and [HorizontalAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment.aspx) properties on your [FrameworkElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.aspx) (including [Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.aspx)). This allows forcing the control to the left, right, top, bottom, or stretching to fill the area it is in.

Combine this with flexible layout controls such as [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid.aspx)s. A top level Grid will fill the screen and can contain rows and columns with relative sizes. This allows the page layout to shrink or grow to cover a fairly wide range of sizes with a single layout.

For larger changes (such as switching between portrait and landscape aspect ratios, or to support a skinny snapped window) you can use VisualStates to either move the controls or to switch between different sets of controls. If the controls are data bound then either set will work automatically with the underlying data.

MSDN has some good documentation on these concepts at [Guidelines for supporting multiple screen sizes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465349.aspx) and [Quickstart: Designing apps for different window sizes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn297195.aspx)